# How do I hide the categories tab under posts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How do I hide the categories tab that you see when you click on the posts in the wordpress dashboard?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove categories submenu by using `remove_submenu_page` function and `admin_menu` action hook. Like this:

```php
add_action('admin_menu', 'removing_category_submenu');

function removing_category_submenu()
{
    remove_submenu_page('edit.php', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category');
}
```

[`remove_submenu_page`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_submenu_page/)

[image]